# Cascading DDL razor pass values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

What I am trying to do is a simple cascading DDL using my database.
Say I have an object class:

```
public class ObjectModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The types are- 'factories', 'samples' and 'sampleresults'.
The moment a user chooses factories- for example- all factories' names are shown.
My Task class has ObjectID member, and an ObjectType member.
So I'd like to pass to ObjectType member the second option while ObjectID gets the first option.
Here is the script I use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Home/Object/List", function (data) {
            var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, object) {
                items += "<option value='" + object.Value + "'>" + object.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Objects").html(items);
        });

        $("#Objects").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Home/ObjectType/List/" + $("#Objects > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, objectType) {
                    items += "<option value='" + objectType.Value + "'>" + objectType.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#ObjectType").html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My view is:

```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ObjectID) 
   <select id="Objects" name="Objects"></select>
    <br />

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ObjectName) 
    <select id="ObjectType" name="ObjectType"></select>
```

My controller is:

```
public ActionResult Create() { return View(); } 

[HttpPost] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public ActionResult Create(Task task) { 
      if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
         db.Tasks.Add(task); 
         db.SaveChanges(); 
         return RedirectToAction("Index"); } 
      return View(task); 
}
```

So it all works fine, and each time I drop the first list down I get all types, then the second DDL shows the relevant names.
The only problem is I have no clue how to pass these values to my model class (Task class).
I am used to use @Html.dropdownlist but it won't work this time I guess, because I'm using script.

Comment: Can you post your controller method that you are trying to POST to? It would help clarify what your expected result is. Also (unrelated to your problem), note that the `ID` of an input element needs to match the property name if you want the `LabelFor` to work correctly for accessibility. If you are using MVC3+, you can use @Html.IdFor(model => model.Property).

Comment: public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Task task)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tasks.Add(task);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(task);
        }

Comment: Thanks, I've added your code to your original post for more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets get the values of those dropdowns first

```
var obj = $('#Objects').val();
var objType = $('#ObjectType').val();
```

Lets say your controller action is TaskAction, we pass those values over as get parameters

```
$.get("/Home/Controller/TaskAction", { object : obj, ObjectType : objType}, function (data) {

    //Do something after
});
```

and lets assume your Task class is like this

```
public class Task
{

    public string Object { get; set;}
    public string ObjectType { get; set;}


}
```

You can then model bind it like this

```
public ActionResult TaskAction(Task myTask)
{

}
```

or explicitly pass it over like this

```
public ActionResult TaskAction(string object, string objType)
{
    new Task{ Object = object, ObjectType = objType}
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I'm kinda new to javascript. when you say- lets get those values, where do I acctually write those 2 lines at?
Where do I write down the '$.get' at? Sorry for those questions, totally new at javascript, it all seems unreadable

Comment: Sorry I should have explained it better - are you wanting to trigger this when an object type has been chosen from the dropdown?

Comment: I wrote all 3 lines at the bottom of the script and checked all values are spelled correctly, they did pass fine. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `name` attribute of a form element matches the name of a **public** property on your model, the ModelBinder will be happy. Note that case matters, and it must be spelled exactly the same. So if your property is **color**, then `name="Colors"` will not bind correctly because of both the capital C and the extra s.

So if you want to bind directly to a `Task` with your existing HTML, `Task` must look like this:

```
public class Task() {
   public Task() { }
   //need a default constructor with no parameters for model binding to work 

   public string Objects { get; set; }
   //property name "Objects" matches value of input/select/textarea's name attribute

   public string ObjectType { get; set; }

   //other methods / properties as needed...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. After checking all names are spelled the same, it did pass values correctly, thanks again